# Passbook passURL not opening the right pass when passes are grouped

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios6, passbook

I have an issue with passbook when trying to open a Pass's passURL as follows:

```
PKPass *pass = .....
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[pass passURL]];
```

Now this works fine in most cases, but when there are many passes in my passbook, sometimes my passes get grouped like so, and have to be swiped through:

[image: passes are grouped and need to be swiped through; see the UIPageControl on the bottom?]

The issue here is that when the passes become grouped in this way, the bit of code I supplied above just opens the group with ANY of the passes in the group on top, not necessarily the one that was supplied in the passURL.

Now here are the things I tested and now know:

- the passes have DIFFERENT pass URL's
- the passes are grouped based on a bunch of criteria; I've had passes from the same organization not be grouped, but sometimes be grouped. Same with styles (coupon, event ticket, etc.)

I looked through Apple's dev forums but saw no mention of this bug (if it indeed is a bug and not my error). I was wondering if anyone else saw it and whether they found some workaround or could reveal my mistake.

Thanks,

EDIT:

All our passes use the exact same pass-type-identifier.

Comment: Does this look like the same issue?   https://devforums.apple.com/thread/173583?tstart=0

Comment: @AlexMartini it might be the same issue in the final post of the thread. There doesn't seem to be a solution though :(

Perhaps I'm supposed to use more varied pass type ID's. The thought had occurred to me, but I didn't see how that would solve the underlying problem, and I don't have admin access on my company's account.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks John. I am facing exactly the same issue. The issue still exists in iOS 6.1.

I also ran some tests, and the grouping logic seems be the following.

- Passes from different pass type IDs are never grouped.
- Passes with different styles (coupon, boarding pass etc) are never grouped.
- Passes with the same pass style may be grouped. The grouping is based on similarity among the data fields, barcode types, maybe some other fields. But it seems the organizationName, description, logoText, foregroundColor and backgroundColor don't play a big role here.

Hope that helps.